# Unable to remove bold font weight on text after blockquote markup

Tags: html

Please I am having issues getting rid of the bold font weight of the text after the blockquote markup in my code. This is a snippet of my code:

```
<blockquote cite="https://books.google.com/?id=sUWP_SM7IrEC&pg=PA98">

<p>I say to you today, my friends, so even though we face the difficulties of today and tomorrow, I still have a dream. It is a dream deeply rooted in the American dream.
I have a dream that one day this nation will rise up and live out the true meaning of its creed: 'We hold these truths to be self-evident</p>

</blockquote>
      <br />
      <p>The speech became known as greatest oratorical speech in the history of America and facilitated the passage of the Civil Right Act of 1964.
    </p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure of your specific styles, but you can always isolate the `<blockquote>` text by applying nested selectors to CSS, to indicate specificity:

```
p {
  font-weight: normal;
}

blockquote p {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: If this method worked, please mark it as the selected answer and upclick. This helps the search filters. Thanks! Glad it worked out for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Open your `<blockquote>` tags after the `p` tag like this:

```
<p>
    <blockquote cite="https://books.google.com/?id=sUWP_SM7IrEC&pg=PA98">I say to you today, my friends, so even though we face the difficulties of today and tomorrow, I still have a dream. It is a dream deeply rooted in the American dream.
I have a dream that one day this nation will rise up and live out the true meaning of its creed: 'We hold these truths to be self-evident
    </blockquote>
</p>
      <br />
<p>The speech became known as greatest oratorical speech in the history of America and facilitated the passage of the Civil Right Act of 1964.</p>
```

---

And you should always make sure all your tags are closed in the right hierarchical order. For example:

```
<p> <---- opening tag

    <b> <---- another opening tag

        **** some text here ****

    </b> <---- closing tag
</p> <---- another closing tag
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help I tried what you wrote, it still did not work but I applied this style instead to the p tags and it worked:

p {
font-weight: normal;
} 
Thanks.